# Selenium webdriver 2.0 : select next user from drop down list and Login\logout in sequence. How can I Loop it in Java

Tags: java, loops, selenium, for-loop

Can anyone help me with this looping in java. I have ~15 user roles that need to be tested with selenium webdriver. There is logout button to click after successful login. Right now with find element my test gets too slow ! 44sec. I need to make it faster, and I think loop may be the better way. Here is the HTML Javascript Code :

```
select name="Role">
<option selected="" value="Consumable Manager">Consumable Manager</option>
<option value="Consumable Warehouse Manager">Consumable Warehouse Manager</option>
<option value="Device Manager">Device Manager</option>
<option value="Manufacturer Manager">Manufacturer Manager</option>
<option value="Operator Manager"> Operator Manager</option>
<option value="Order Manager"> Order Manager</option>
<option value="Shipment Manager"> Shipment Manager</option>
<option value="Site Configuration Manager"> Site Configuration Manager</option>
<option value="Site Order Manager"> Site Order Manager</option>
<option value="Read Only User"> Read Only User</option>
<option value="Warehouse Manager"> Warehouse Manager</option>
<option value="CIF Card Receiving Manager"> CIF Card Receiving Manager</option>
<option value="CIF PIN Letter Receiving Manager"> CIF PIN Letter Receiving Manager</option>
<option value="CIF Card Shipping Manager"> CIF Card Shipping Manager</option>
<option value="CIF PIN Letter Shipping Manager"> CIF PIN Letter Shipping Manager</option>
</select>
```

I have done find element by selectByVisibleText

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Role"))).selectByVisibleText("Manufacturer Manager");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"Logout\"]")).click();
```

I have this Code, but I only get list of Role. not the action of login logout :

```
 List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
        System.out.println(options.size());

        for(int i=0; i<options.size(); i++){

        System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());
    }
```

I have long code for each Role, which is not reliable. your advise is appreciated. Please help me with Loop sample code if possible.

Comment: Can anyone help me please with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If you want to loop you can use testNG data provider
or Jsystem loop (what ever you use)
for faster UI test 
you need to verify 
1. Use Explicit Waits and not Implicit Waits
2. Don't open the browser in every test 
3. You can use htmlunit (Fastest implementation of WebDriver)
4. DONT USE SLEEP !!!

hope that will help
```

Answer (score 0):

Use testNG + dataprovider, where will be enumerated all roles (lines from dropdown) + login details
This approach also will test, that all roles are there in the dropdown
This will minimize tests time by removing findElements

Some dataproviders [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm)